# What is a simple model of internal combustion engine?

Tags: heat-engine, combustion

Let's look at an internal combustion engine (more precisely a standard gasoline car engine) as a black box (so without going too much into details about internal processes).
The inputs of this system are throttle (gas pedal position), moment of inertia it sees and possibly external torque? And the outputs are torque and angular velocity.

Can you provide me with a simple model of these relations? Or in other words, how do I know how throttle affects the movement of the car?

Comment: Um...pressing the gas pedal down will accelerate the car? I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: The problem is a bit more complex as you have transmission gears constantly changing the moment of inertia the motor sees, it behaves differently when you're going uphill and so on.

Edit: Also, when you're going uphill, how do you know how much you need to press the gas pedal? And how does the motor behave when you press it less than that, exactly that, more than that, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is completely off-topic, if it was more exclusively about the basic working of the internal combustion engine (as opposed to the details of how the motion of the pistons drives the rotation of the wheels) then it'd be OK. As mentioned in my answer, the internal combustion engine is just an example of a thermodynamic cycle called the "Otto cycle", which is discussed in *Thermal Physics* by Schroeder, a common text for undergraduate courses in thermodynamics and statistical mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to analyze different types of engines is in thermodynamic terms, dividing one cycle of the engine into phases similar to the four phases of a [heat engine](http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~cfadd/1360/22HeatEngines/Carnot.html), and noting which phases are approximately adiabatic (no heat enters or leaves) and what thermodynamic quantities are held approximately constant in each phase, and diagramming the whole thing on a [pressure volume diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_volume_diagram). The book [*An Introduction to Thermal Physics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201380277) by Daniel Schroeder has this type of analysis for the internal combustion engine on p. 131:

> The working substance is a gas, initially a mixture of air and
>   vaporized gasoline. This mixture is first injected into a cylinder and
>   compressed, adiabatically, by a piston. A spark plug then ignites the
>   mixture, raising its temperature and pressure while the volume doesn't
>   change. Next the high-pressure gas pushes the piston outward,
>   expanding adiabatically and producing mechanical work. Finally, the
>   hot exhaust gases are expelled and replaced by a new mixture at lower
>   temperature and pressure. The whole cycle is shown in Figure 4.5,
>   where I've represented the exhaust/replacement steps as if it were
>   simply a lowering of pressure due to the extraction of heat. What
>   actually happens is that the piston pushes the old mixture out
>   through a valve and pulls a new mixture in through another valve,
>   expelling heat but doing no net work. This cycle is called the **Otto
>   cycle**, after the German inventor Nikolaus August Otto.

The pressure-temperature diagram in the book ('Figure 4.5' mentioned above) is basically the same as the one on [this page](http://universe-review.ca/R13-09-thermodynamics06.htm) detailing different types of engines:

[image]

More on the Otto cycle [here](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/airplane/otto.html). As mentioned by others in comments though, a detailed description of how the motion of the pistons in the engine is used to drive the rotation of the tires seems more like engineering than physics, apparently the whole system is called the [powertrain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powertrain) which you can see diagrammed [here](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/media/120680/The-main-elements-of-the-power-train-of-a-front):

[image]

Google any of the labels to find more info, but if you're wondering about how the up-and-down motion of the pistons is turned into rotation, I think the torque converter is the part to read up on, the article [here](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/auto-parts/towing/towing-capacity/information/torque-converter2.htm) looks like a good introduction.

And as far as how the gas pedal controls the speed, [here](http://www.driving-test-success.com/how-cars-work.htm) is another good page on how car engines works which says that the basic idea is that "The harder a driver presses on the accelerator pedal the more fuel-air mix is passed into the cylinders and the more power is produced". [This page](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/fuel-injection2.htm) says that it's just a matter of the pedal controlling a valve that determines how much air enters the cylinders, and that "The engine control unit (ECU, the computer that controls all of the electronic components on your engine) "sees" the throttle valve open and increases the fuel rate in anticipation of more air entering the engine" (not sure how the fuel rate was controlled on older cars without computers). And apparently the amount of air and fuel in the cylinders controls how quickly they complete each stroke, and because of other elements of the powertrain like the torque converter, this determines the speed the wheels rotate.

[Here](http://mb-soft.com/public2/engine.html) is another quite detailed page about the physics of car engines, if you want more.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to look at it is as you press the accelerator pedal down you allow more fuel and air into the combustion chamber (black box) which has a given chemical potential energy per given unit mass. The more you press the pedal the more mass (energy) goes into your 'black box' hence increasing output (torque, angular velocity).

That is about as simplified as I can make it without going to the inner workings of an internal combustion motor, hope it helps!